# Why does registering a subclass with its superclass in +initialize present a chicken and egg issue? (objc)

Tags: objective-c, initialization

Just reading an excerpt from this [website](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html).

> Because +initialize runs lazily, it's obviously not a good place to
>   put code to register a class that otherwise wouldn't get used. For
>   example, NSValueTransformer or NSURLProtocol subclasses can't use
>   +initialize to register themselves with their superclasses, because you set up a chicken-and-egg situation.

I understand that `+initialize` is run once per class when the first message is sent to that class. Also, if any of the subclasses do not implement their own `+initialize`, the `+initialize` method will be run again in the superclass.

I am just not 100% on why registering a subclass with its superclass in its own `+initialize` method would present a chicken and egg problem.

Is it because the superclass may have never had its `+initialize` invoked, and you are trying to register your subclass with its superclass in a method that depends on the superclass calling its `+initialize` first?

Just a little bit of further clarification would go a long way for me, thank you.

Comment: Both answers are really good, and have helped me immensely, I don't know which one to accept!

Comment: Keep in mind that `+initialize` can be invoked multiple times in a single class.  You generally need to protect the implementation to only be invoked once;  use `dispatch_once()` or `if (self == [Thing class]) { ... initialize ... }`.  (The reason this happens is if any subclasses don't implement `+initialize`, then the super's implementation is invoked by way of inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two extracts from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) on the `initialize` method:

> The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program. The runtime sends the initialize message to classes in a thread-safe manner. Superclasses receive this message before their subclasses.
>
> ...
>
> Because initialize is called in a thread-safe manner and the order of initialize being called on different classes is not guaranteed, it’s important to do the minimum amount of work necessary in initialize methods. Specifically, any code that takes locks that might be required by other classes in their initialize methods is liable to lead to deadlocks. Therefore you should not rely on initialize for complex initialization, and should instead limit it to straightforward, class local initialization.

The `initialize` message is sent to a class the first time the runtime encounters it, for example the first time you need to allocate that class or the first time you access its `sharedInstance` method (in case of a singleton), and it acquires some locks in order to guarantee the thread safety. If you make references to subclasses from within this method, you can get into a deadlock situation, as both the base class and the subclass will lock onto the same thing.

For example, let's consider the scenario of a superclass `MyClass` and one of it's children `MySubclass`:

```
@interface MyClass
@end

@interface MySubclass: MyClass
@end

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)initialize {
    [MySubclass doSomething];
}
```

When the runtime encounters the first usage of `MyClass`, it acquires a lock, and calls the class method `initialize`. Now, when executing the method it realises that this is also the first time it encounters `MySubclass`, and must also intialize it before the class can do some actual work. And what does this trigger? Yes, you've guessed, another call to `+[MyClass initialize]`.

This how we end up in the chicken-egg situation, or to put it more technical - the deadlock, or the recursion. `MyClass` calls on `MySubclass`, this means that `MySubclass` needs to be initialized before `MyClass` is used. However `MySubclass` is a child of `MyClass`, so `MyClass` should be initialized first. So, which one the two should be first initialized?

Answer (score 3):

Take the example of `NSURLProtocol`.  The way it's used is that registered subclasses are asked, in turn, if they can handle a request.  The first to answer yes gets an instance created and the request is handed off.

The `initialize` method is only called if a message is sent to the class.  Since only registered subclasses are asked to handle a request, you can't register in `initialize` because it won't ever be invoked.